# pointer to a pointer in C functions

Tags: c, pointers

I have struct User

```
struct User
{
    char login[LOG_IN]; 
    char password_hash[PASS_IN]; 
    struct User* next; 
};
```

And i have function that might change argument pointer.

```
void deleteFirstUser(User** head)
{
    //something like
    *head = *head->next;
}
```

How it can works?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: @aschepler what syntax I need to use in `deleteFirstUser()` function? `*head = *head->next;` is wrong.

Comment: `struct User *tmp = (*head)->next; free(*head); *head = tmp;`

Comment: `*head->next` -> `(*head)->next`, but this creates a memory leak.

Comment: Also: `void deleteFirstUser(User** head)` is wrong, it should be `void deleteFirstUser(struct User** head)`. `User** head` would be correct in C++ but not in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky , pmg thanks a lot

Comment: (Unless you've done `typedef struct User User;` somewhere else to make the shorter name `User` valid.)

Answer (score 0):

To delete the `head` element in a single linked list, you need to
1) assign a temporary pointer to the next element of `head`
2) call free on `head`
3) assign `head` the temporary pointer

code

```
void deleteFirstUser(User **head){
    User *tmp;
    tmp=(*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    (*head)=tmp;
    return;
}
```